# Java swing questions in ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

```
//GUI.java
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 870343916997182570L;
    private JPanel btmPanel;

    public GUI(String arg0) throws HeadlessException {
        super(arg0);
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //ResultPanel rslt = new ResultPanel();
        //this.getContentPane().add(rslt.createPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        btmPanel = new JPanel();
        btmPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btmPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton blueSearch = new JButton("Search");
        blueSearch.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        blueSearch.addActionListener(this);
        btmPanel.add(blueSearch);

        JButton blackChart = new JButton("Chart");
        blackChart.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        blackChart.addActionListener(this);
        btmPanel.add(blackChart);

        this.getContentPane().add(btmPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);    
    }   

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String buttonString = e.getActionCommand();

        if (buttonString.equals("Search")) {
            ResultPanel rslt = new ResultPanel();
            this.getContentPane().add(rslt.createPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }

}

//ResultPanel.java
public class ResultPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7851502165390304971L;
    private JPanel textPanel;
    private JTextArea textDisplay;

    public ResultPanel() {
        textPanel = new JPanel(); 
        textDisplay = new JTextArea("Text Area:");
    }

    public JPanel createPanel() {

        textDisplay.setEditable(true);
        textPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textPanel.add(textDisplay,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return textPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }

}
```

I have two buttons on the main frame, and I hope to change the panel when I press the button.

The question is that the code in "actionPerformed" doesn't work,

but it works well if I put them in the creatGUI()....(see the marked section).

Is that anything wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked that the actionPerformed method is being called at all? Printing something to the console from it is the easiest

Comment: Use a `CardLayout`  as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005) (and a `ButtonGroup` with `JRadioButton` instances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `pack();` after you add the panel. This will get the JFrame to show the update.

```
    if (buttonString.equals("Search")) {
        ResultPanel rslt = new ResultPanel();
        this.getContentPane().add(rslt.createPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After adding components on the run, to your `JFrame` you need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` for changing to be visible.

Though as you said, if you are adding them inside the `createGUI()`, that way it is visible, since at that time it's a static addition to your Swing Application, you added that first and then set it to visible.

Though your code has a bit of loopholes, the best I can tell you real quick, is you extending `JPanel` for `ResultPanel`, though you never used `ResultPanel`, so I modified your code to take `ResultPanel` into perspective. Here try this modified code from your example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AddComponentExample
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel btmPanel;
    private ResultPanel resultPanel;

    public AddComponentExample()
    {
        resultPanel = new ResultPanel();
    }

    private void display()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Adding Component Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btmPanel = new JPanel();
        btmPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btmPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton blueSearch = new JButton("Search");
        blueSearch.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        blueSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (!resultPanel.isShowing())
                {
                    resultPanel = resultPanel.createPanel();
                    frame.getContentPane().add(resultPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    frame.revalidate();  // For Java 7 and above.
                    // frame.getContentPane().revalidate(); // For Java 1.6 or below.
                    frame.repaint(); // required sometimes
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Panel is already Visible");
            }
        });
        btmPanel.add(blueSearch);

        JButton blackChart = new JButton("Chart");
        blackChart.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //blackChart.addActionListener(this);
        btmPanel.add(blackChart);

        frame.getContentPane().add(btmPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new AddComponentExample().display();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ResultPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7851502165390304971L;
    private JPanel textPanel;
    private JTextArea textDisplay;

    public ResultPanel() {
        textPanel = new JPanel(); 
        textDisplay = new JTextArea("Text Area:");
    }

    public ResultPanel createPanel() {

        textDisplay.setEditable(true);
        textPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textPanel.add(textDisplay,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(textPanel);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *anonymous class* of **ActionListener**

Answer (score 0):

```
Use one line of code: this.revalidate();
This will validate and repaint the frame so that it can show the JPanel.

if (buttonString.equals("Search")) {
  ResultPanel rslt = new ResultPanel();
  this.getContentPane().add(rslt.createPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
  this.revalidate();
}
```